# How to extract Twitter username from Search API via PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, twitter, atom-feed

The Twitter Search api returns results in ATOM/XML format which look like this:

```
<author>
  <name>username (Friendly Name)</name>
  <uri>http://twitter.com/username</uri>
</author>
```

In my PHP I can get the name field as a variable, so it would look like this:

```
$names = "username (Friendly Name)"
```

But I want to use PHP to extract them as seperate variables, like this:

```
$username = "username"
$friendlyName = "Friendly Name" (without parantheses)
```

TIA!

Answer (score 3):

A non-regex solution:

```
$names = 'username (Friendly Name)';
list($username, $friendlyName) = explode('(', $names);
$username = trim($username);
$friendlyName = trim($friendlyName, ')');
```

Assumes that parentheses are not valid in either name.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do, I suppose :

```
$names = "username (Friendly Name)";
if (preg_match('/^(.*?) \((.*)\)$/', $names, $m)) {
    var_dump($m[1], $m[2]);
}
```

And you're getting, in this case :

```
string 'username' (length=8)
string 'Friendly Name' (length=13)
```

*(Note the "`string`", "`length`", and all that are only the output of `var_dump`, and not the actual variables content)*

Basically, the regex is matching :

- Anything from the beginning of the string to a space
- Then, anything between `()`
- And those are the two returned patterns -- as they are between non-escaped `()` ; which means they'll be in `$m[1]` and `$m[2]`